# How do I close a terminal without saving the history?

Tags: bash, command-history

More than once I've accidentally run a number of commands and polluted my bash history. How do I close my terminal without saving my bash history? I'm using Fedora.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your shell's history is saved in the file indicated by the `HISTFILE` variable. So:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

This also applies to zsh, but not to ksh which keeps saving to the file indicated by `$HISTFILE` when the shell starts (and conversely, you decide to save your history in ksh once you've started the shell).

Comment: I can use this before i log out after i polluted the history? and its ust for this session? i dont need to `set HISTFILE` next time i log in? (just say if this is correct or incorrect)

Comment: @acidzombie24 That is correct, changes to environment variables are not saved across sessions unless you store the changes explicitly, e.g. in rc files.

Answer (score 48):

There's more than a few ways to accomplish this.

*Note: These options are **not** mutually exclusive; they can be used in any combination, or all at once.*

### Option 0

Delete the `HISTFILE` shell variable.

```bash
unset HISTFILE
```

According to the man page this will remove the shell's ability to automatically write any history to a file, regardless of if you set `HISTFILE` to something after unsetting it.

### Option 1

If you're a perfectionist when it comes to cluttering up your history file, then what you can do is modify the `HISTIGNORE` variable to include globs of commands you don't want recorded. For instance, if you add `HISTIGNORE='ls*:cd*'` to your `~/.bashrc` then any instance of `ls` and `cd` aren't inserted into your history file.

This variable respects `extglob` when turned on:

```bash
shopt -s extglob
# With `extglob` on I can use extended globs to ignore all:
# cd ..
# cd ../
# cd ..//
# cd ../..
# cd ../../
# cd ../..//
# etc.
HISTIGNORE='cd +(..|../)*(/)'
```

This will ignore `cd ..`, `cd ../`, `cd ../..`, etc but leave `cd myfolder`.

More information on extended globs can be found in the [bash man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

### Option 2

If you want to control on a command-by-command basis what commands get left out of your history, you can set `HISTCONTROL='ignorespace'` which will omit any command lines starting with a space. Using `ignoreboth` will also omit repeated lines. Then, hitting the space bar before you enter a command will cause it to not show up in your history file.

```bash
# With HISTCONTROL=ignorespace (or =ignoreboth) this line gets written to history
$ mycommand
# But this line does not
$  mycommand
```

### Option 3

If you just want to make it so when you close the terminal the shell exits immediately, you can `trap` the signal the terminal program sends the shell (`xterm`, for instance sends `SIGHUP` then waits for the shell to exit) and make exit without saving the history when it receives this signal. Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
# don't record history when the window is closed
trap 'unset HISTFILE; exit' SIGHUP
```

### Option 4

While some may consider this the "barbarian" approach, sending `SIGKILL` to your shell's PID will kill your shell right away without the shell being able to do *anything* such as trap the signal, save history, execute `~/.bash_logout`, warn about stopped jobs, or any of that good stuff.

(`$$` expands to the PID of the shell process executing the command)

```bash
kill -9 $$
```

Comment: +1 for the 'kill -9 $$' method. That's certainly one way around situations where HISTIGNORE, etc are set as read-only.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to promote using `kill -9` for anything except dire situations when everything else has failed.

Comment: Sending SIGKILL _never_ a good idea as a standard operating procedure.  Use the proper procedures, like unsetting HISTFILE.

Comment: @Arcege TMTOWTDI.

Comment: I wanted to know the opposite - alas how to kill bash making sure it WILL save his history - and this answered my question, thanks.

Comment: `kill -9 $$` is ideal to execute if you accidentally entered your password in the shell and hit enter (expecting a password prompt instead).

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised to see no one has suggested `history -c` immediately prior to `exit`. IINM (I'm no expert) that will do nicely.

Comment: You're on the right track: `history -r` will re-read the history file, so saving becomes a no-op.

Comment: Flushing the history is a bad habit... shell history contains a lot of useful information about who did what. it's very useful for people who are new on your platforms (unless you are 100% confident about you documentation, change management)

Answer (score 2):

There are two environment variables that bash uses to determine the history file and how many lines to write to it when the shell exits.

You can throw away your session's history with either of these (set during the session you want to omit from your history file):

```
HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

or

```
HISTSIZE=0
```

Either of these work fine in Bash on Fedora

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you care about your command history so much. If you need certain commands often, you might have more fun if you define aliases for them so you can get them back with two keystrokes rather than having to look for them in the history.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Eli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1323/eli-heady) already gave you the correct answer for Bash which is to set `HISTSIZE=0`.
2. I would just add the method to do it for [GNU screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). Press `Ctrl+A` (screen escape sequence) followed by `:scrollback 0`. This will delete scroll-back history. Now you can immediately do `:scrollback 15000` to reset scroll-back buffer size.

Comment: When did the OP say they were using `screen(1)`?

Comment: He didn't. But, you could be running Bash inside a screen session and HISTSIZE=0 will still leave your activity details in screen's scroll-back buffer. So, if you really want it clean, you have to do `scrollback=0` as well.

Comment: The scrollback buffer is cleared when the window closes (i.e. when the shell exits). What about if you typed Ctrl-a H? Will it kill the logfile?

Comment: @amphetamachine: nope, it will only begin/end logging of current window. Neighther `Ctrl+a H` nor `Ctrl+a :clear` will remove history. You need `Ctrl+a :scrollback 0`.

You can test it yourself. Start a fresh screen session. Now do a `cat /etc/passwd`. Now, do any of the above - `Ctrl+a H` or `Ctrl+a :clear`. Now, try copying from screen buffer by donig a `Ctrl+a [` followed by up-arrow to go up and see how far you can go to copy. If you have done a `Ctrl+a :scrollback` followed by a `clear`, you would only go as far as you can see in current window since there wont be any scrollback buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a safe/natural alternative which should work if you are connected to a unix server via an SSH/telnet client such as PuTTY, which is something that I don't like when it happens, but when you want it to happen, then just let the connection on without interacting with the window until it gets lost when the timeout limit hits, or you can also go ahead and disconnect from internet and try to type something until it disconnects similarly due to network error. This way your commands from that session get lost because you don't properly exit when it would normally save them to history. I don't know if this approach can be applied somehow for a computer that is running unix itself.