# Methods for avoiding bash history logging?

Tags: bash, command-history

What are some tricks for avoiding bash history being logged in a fascist logging environment that does not involve modifying `.bashrc` or deleting content from within the history file?

Comment: use another shell e.g. `sh`

Comment: So that means no `rm ~/.bash_history; ln -s /dev/null ~/.bash_history`?

Comment: Depending on how often you want to do that, see [Temporarily suspend bash_history on a given shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10922) or [How do I close a terminal without saving the history?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25049)

Comment: Also, unset `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  This is the default `$PROMPT_COMMAND` on a server I have access to: `history -a >(tee -a ~/.bash_history | logger -t "$USER[$$] $SSH_CONNECTION")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you have .bash_profile, and this startup file calling .bashrc? Do you have write permission on .bash_profile?

Otherwise, if you just don't want to log some commands, run

```
$ unset HISTFILE
```

then all commands afterwards won't be logged within that session.

Answer (score 11):

One possible solution is to stop logging bash history is:

```
set +o history
```

and to reset, that is to start logging again:

```
set -o history
```

Answer (score 3):

On stackoverflow they had [some decent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640403/can-you-prevent-a-command-from-going-into-the-bash-shell-command-history):

- Add a space to your command.
- Add [ \t]* to HISTIGNORE
- Add ignorespace to your HISTCONTROL environment variable

Although not all of them may apply for your situation, those seems like the only options.

Comment: It's important to note that HISTIGNORE/HISTCONTROL stop commands from being added to the history list. This probably keeps them from being logged, too, but it also makes them impossible to access with normal history keys (like up and down arrow, ctrl-R, etc.) So if you're used to editing and repeating previously typed commands, these settings are really annoying.

Comment: Adding a space specifically requires the *first character* to be a space, right?

Comment: @phs yes - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces