# Why is bash not storing commands that start with spaces?

Tags: bash, command-history, whitespace

If I perform a sequence of commands like:

```
$ ls
$ grep abc file.txt
```

and then use the up arrow key to get the previous one, the terminal will show the last cmd (which is the `grep` here)

But if I do something like this:

```
$ ls
$   grep abc file.txt
```

where `grep` is preceded by spaces, pressing up gives `ls`, not `grep`.

Why is this?

Comment: Follow-up: [Why does bash have a HISTCONTROL=ignorespace option?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115934/why-does-bash-have-a-histcontrol-ignorespace-option)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoreboth
```

If you want to change this behaviour add a new line to your `~/.bashrc` file (which will affect every new shell you open):

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

(assuming you still want to filter out duplicates)

man bash:

> HISTCONTROL
>
> A  colon-separated  list  of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.  If the list of values includes `ignorespace`, lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list. A value of `ignoredups` causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved. A value of `ignoreboth` is shorthand for `ignorespace` and `ignoredups`.

Comment: and `HISTCONTROL` is set to `ignoreboth` in the default `~/.bashrc` provided by `debian` at least.

Comment: What is the use case of `ignorespace`?

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 the default is `ignoreboth` which is kind-of annoying.

Comment: Ciro, I assume it's so that you can enter command like `echo "drop database mydb" | mysql -u root -pPassword` and not have it saved in history.

Comment: @Jeremy yes, that seems like a legitimate use case

Comment: For mac users, HISTCONTROL is not set to anything, so you'll need to add it to your bash_profile or similar - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces

Answer (score -2):

Add the line `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups` to ~/.bashrc (or /.bash_profile) then, from the command line, run `source ~/.bashrc` (or /.bash_profile) to implement the changes to the current shell session

Comment: This duplicates the accepted answer.