# Why does bash have a HISTCONTROL=ignorespace option?

Tags: bash, command-history, whitespace

Or to phrase it differently, why would you want to prevent commands from being written to the bash history?

(Inspired by a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces).)

Comment: This is a thread on bash's mailing list related to your question: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-02/msg00024.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The one thing I use that the initial space for is if I want to be able to restart an older commandline that starts with the same command  (`!ls` e.g.) and I need to be able to re-execute the older one, but not the newer.

The other time I use it is in the (seldom) cases I give a password on the commandline, I rather not have those stored in the `.bash_history` file once I exit `bash`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather not know how many times I've played [crawl](http://crawl.develz.org/)!

Occasionally I like to do a `history | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n | tail` to see my most-issued commands.  I want to see a ranking in there of commands I find interesting (things like `ls`, `svn`, `p4`, `for`, and `cd`) and I feel better when I don't see games in that list.  So when I run something that I don't want to see in that list, I prefix it with a space.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the Q.

Comment: I don't know: it is a valid use of the variable (and it is expressed with a degree of humour and geekiness). Upvoted.

Comment: you can add the games you play to HISTIGNORE to avoid getting it in history file

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Anthon: It is not just possible to avoid similar command lines in history but from time to time there is a need to do that: I often analyze OpenPGP certificates in the shell. That means that 15 lines (sometimes more) are thrown in the console. You do that a few times and your history is full. Even worse: History does not work well if the command covers the whole screen (bash). The start of the command is not shown correctly and thus can hardly be edited.

Thus I keep a rather short one of these command lines in the history and block the other ones.

Comment: You should make your bash history size (number of items or lines) unlimited
`export HISTFILESIZE=-1`