# How do I open an incognito bash session?

Tags: bash, shell, command-history, privacy

Is it possible to open an incognito session in `bash`?

For example, when we need to enter passwords in commands and don't want `bash` to add them to history.

Comment: `cat | bash` will run a non-interactive `bash` without prompt, command-line editing (just the line discipline's internal editor) or history.

Comment: Write a space in front of your command: ' secretcommand'. Now `secrectcommand` will not be in bash history.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

When you want `bash` to stop logging your commands, just unset the `HISTFILE` variable:

```
HISTFILE=
```

All further commands should then no longer be logged to `.bash_history`.

On the other hand, if you are actually supplying passwords as arguments to commands, you're already doing something wrong. `.bash_history` is not world-readable and therefore not the biggest threat in this situation:

`ps` and `/proc` are the big problem. All users on the system can see the commands you're currently running *with all of their arguments*. Passing passwords as command line arguments is therefore **inherently insecure**. Use environment variables or config files (that you have chmodded 600) to securely supply passwords.

Comment: I've been using Linux 10+ years and never thought to do this +1

Comment: `unset HISTFILE` has a similar effect. I have a function for this: `n() { HISTFILE=; PS1="~${PS1#\~}"; }`. That way I can clearly see whether I am in "incognito mode" or not.

Comment: +1 for addressing the real problem rather than merely answering the question. An additional option for passing around credentials are Unix domain sockets.

Comment: Another useful tip would be to put a space before i.e. " HISTFILE=". any command with space before does not gets logged.

Comment: Another cool thing about this is that even previous commands on that window are also ignores. It is like turning existing session to incognito :p

Comment: @FUD that with thespace is really cool. Regarding passwords in the shell, what are you supposed to do when something expects a token, password or other kinda secret in a command? although those usually only run for a short time to set themselves up or whatever so PS isnt a huge issue

Answer (score 40):

```
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

If this option is not already set for `bash`, it may be just what you need.  It is less debilitating than disabling all history. With that set, any commandline starting with a space character will not be saved to the history list.

From these related links:

[Why does bash have a HISTCONTROL=ignorespace option?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115934/why-does-bash-have-a-histcontrol-ignorespace-option)

[Why is bash not storing commands that start with spaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces)

Comment: Note this is often the default.

Answer (score 5):

You can temporarily disable history: `set +o history`

```
set +o history
...
set -o history
```

There is a difference between disabling history and unsetting `HISTFILE`:

```
HISTFILE=
date
ls
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
history
```

outputs something like this:

```
84  HISTFILE=
85  date
87  ls
88  HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
89  history
```

i.e. all commands are saved in the history list. Type `exit` to save it.
But

```
set +o history
date
ls
set -o history
history
```

outputs something like this:

```
115  set +o history
116  history
```

**Summary**:
`set +o history` for long sessions.
`HISTCONTROL` and `<space>command` at other time.