# Using only in-memory command history

Tags: bash, command-history

How can I prevent Bash from writing history entries to disk? My `~/.bashrc`contains the line

```
trap 'unset HISTFILE; exit' SIGHUP
```

but it doesn't have the desired effect. If I run `history -c && history -w; exit` and open a new terminal, the history is empty, but if I type some more commands and exit, the commands are in the history when I open a new terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing `w`rite permission on the history file?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz That works but in my book it's more of a workaround than a clean solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following line in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

> HISTFILE - The name of the file in which command history is saved. The default value is ~/.bash_history.  If unset, the command history is not saved when a shell exits.

`HISTFILE=` works too.

Comment: Yes, simply adding `unset HISTFILE` to `~/.bashrc` seems to work. If you clean up your answer I can accept it.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom, ok. Bonus: [How do I open an incognito bash session?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158933/how-do-i-open-an-incognito-bash-session/211096#211096)