# Commands pasted into bash not recorded in history

Tags: bash, command-history, clipboard

From time to time I find that when I copy/paste a command from a web page (or from the Terminal window itself) the pasted command is not recorded in bash history. For example, just now I did this:

```
cd foo
    git push --set-upstream origin master
cd ../foo2
    git push --set-upstream origin master
cd ../foo3/
    git push --set-upstream origin master
cd ../foo4
    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

(**Note:** I typed the `cd` commands manually - the `git push` commands were pasted).

However when I type `history` I see this:

```
 2008  cd foo
 2009  cd ../foo2
 2010  cd ../foo3/
 2011  cd ../foo4
 2012  history
```

Bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Linux version:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Terminal version:

```
Gnome Terminal 3.6.2
```

This is kind-of annoying, because for one thing `history` does not show exactly what I did. Secondly, I can't just up-arrow to recall the command I just pasted.

Why is it doing this, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Are those spaces literally there ? Before the git commands

Comment: Yes, I tried to push on its own (`git push`) and got an error message, suggesting that I do `git push --set-upstream origin master`. The message (from git) was indented like that (I may have the exact number of spaces wrong because the history pushed the message out of the terminal window). I copied the entire line, so some leading spaces are there.

Comment: Thanks! When I searched, and also started typing the question, I did not see that particular thread. Thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: Np. Easy to miss if you do not know the cause :) Gl

Comment: To change this behavior, check the manpage and look for HISTCONTROL. For exmaple, `export HISTCONTROL=""` in .bashrc would do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the `bash` manpage:

> lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list.

The commands you pasted have spaces in front of the command and are therefore not saved in history.

Comment: Ah yes, and I can (of course) read the bash manpage, and I even have a bash book. Still, things like that can slip by you when you aren't expecting them. In general, we expect that bash does not particularly care about spaces. For example `cd#foo` and `cd##foo` (where `#` represents a space) are expected to give the same results. Personally I would like bash to default to not doing that, but I am only one, amongst many. :)

Comment: So what's the workaround? Because commands get executed, but not kept in history.

Comment: See the comment on my question. `export HISTCONTROL=""` in .bashrc would do the trick.

Comment: Also see <https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917>