# How to disable "Program '/bin/bash' crashed" warning when killing the shell?

Tags: shell, terminal, terminal-emulator

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04. When I exiting terminal emulator (konsole or yakuake) by doing something like `kill -9 $$` it doesn't close, and saying:

> Warning: Program '/bin/bash' crashed.

How could I disable this behavior and force terminal emulator to silently close when shell is killed?

In the same system, when prompting `kill -9 $$` in `xterm`, it exits without any crash reported.

I don't remember exactly, in which Linux distributions I saw such "silent" behavior from-the-box, but there are some.

Update: the reason to do so is to exit terminal emulator without saving history to `.bash_history`.

Comment: Why do you want to kill the shell rather than letting it terminate gracefully so it can clean up after itself, eg save its history file?

Comment: What happens if you send SIGHUP instead of SIGKILL ?

Comment: My main case to do so is exactly to avoid saving shell history after some crap accidently pasted into open terminal emulator.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case. :) Try SIGABRT, that should prevent history from being saved without causing bash to crash. FWIW, I don't get a crash with SIGKILL, but I'm currently using a different terminal (rxvt), although I generally use konsole on Mepis 11.

Comment: `kill -SIGABRT $$` returns the same error =(

I guess the problem is in terminal emulator, not in shell itself.

Comment: I've just been playing with this stuff in konsole, so I see what you mean. But there's some useful info in [How do I close a terminal without saving the history?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25049/88378)

Comment: As your goal is to avoid history entries, try `history -d`. As this is a bash built-in, details are in `help history`.

Comment: What happens with `kill -9 $PPID` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please consider editing `/etc/profile`.  At the bottom add:

```
unset HISTFILE && exit
```

for your current session.  If wanting all history gone, try:

```
rm -f $HISTFILE && unset HISTFILE && exit
```

Killing an app is not the most graceful approach.  See [Quit Bash Shell Without Saving Bash History (5 Methods)](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/quit-bash-shell-without-saving-bash-history/).  Avoid #2, as this is what you are trying now.

Comment: Thank you, that's solving my issue. So I could now make an alias for bash, something like `alias french_exit='unset HISTFILE && exit'`