# How to clear the bash history when i close the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, kde, konsole

Using KDE Konsole as a bash terminal I would like to clear the history when I close the terminal (tab/application), note that I do need the bash history when Konsole is still open (to search it); I would like to have it cleared once the terminal is closed.

I often use the terminal for a long time and clear the history before I close the terminal, I am looking for a way to automate the clearing of the history.

I found a similar questions on how to clear the history or how to disable it like [How do I close a terminal without saving the history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25049/how-do-i-close-a-terminal-without-saving-the-history), however I found nothing helpful for my situation. The difference here is that i do need the history file while the terminal is running, setting `unset HISTFILE` disable the history file after that command is ran and does not **clear** the history file itself. Note that the history file is needed while the session is running but when it get closed it need to be cleared.

How can we clear the bash history when the terminal gets closed?

Comment: Why is disabling it per https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25049/5132 not helpful?  How does it not do exactly what you want?

Comment: Maybe it is being saved as it goes along. You need to disable it. Probably in `~/.bashrc`. Do you have a history add in (for example) your shell prompt?

Comment: @JdeBP i still need the history during the session, disabling it completely is not intended.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks for the edit :) ... i do search the history for the current session but once I am done using the terminal (often a long time...) i do cleat the history manually... i was looking for a way to automate that "clear"

Comment: If you need to clarify the question then edit it.

Comment: erase .bash_history and put a trap in bashrc `trap "history  -c" EXIT`

Comment: @origami upvoting is not an automatic process. You can likely attract upvotes by improving a little on your question, e.g. include the reason _why_ the other question you found doesn't suit your needs - having it only in the comments is not helpful, because comments are difficult to read and may be deleted without notice - or referring to other tutorials and how-to's you have found (again, with explanation why they don't suit your needs).

Comment: The other question is _not about_ disabling it completely.  It's about _stopping it being saved to file_, exactly as here.  So, again, how do the likes of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25050/5132 not do exactly what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I close a terminal without saving the history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25049/how-do-i-close-a-terminal-without-saving-the-history)

Comment: The difference here is that i do need the history while the terminal is running, setting `unset HISTFILE` disable the history file after that command is ran and does not **clear** the history file itself. The history file is needed while the session is running but when it get closed it need to be cleared. some answers here solve the question :)

Comment: @origami this is what unsetting `HISTFILE` does (it tells bash not save history contents after exiting - it does not affect the history mechanism whilst using bash). What may be confusing you that `.bash_history` may _already_ have entries in it. In which case `rm ~/.bash_history` and then the unset `HISTFILE` setting will no longer re-create it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. erase `.bash_history`

   ```
   cat /dev/null > .bash_history
   ```

   or

   ```
   >.bash_history
   ```
2. add a trap to `.bashrc`

   ```
   trap "history  -c" EXIT
   ```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`.

Comment: @rexkogitans just as it's useless to improve a cmd that it will be run once in life , the thing is about clearing history onexit , and the op has right to erase his bash_history or just keep some useful history entries that will stay persistance !

Comment: When someone comments on a [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat), implying that somehow such a comment is denying people rights is a rather absurd response.

Comment: @JdeBP sorry if you got it like that , but i didn't mean any offence or denaying people!

Comment: @Yunus Do you know what the trap history is accomplishing? Could someone add explanation to this otherwise fine answer?

Comment: @stevek-pro trap used to execute something on exit or other signal, according to this case when you exit terminal it will clear history before being saved to histfile

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The trap is not working for me for some reason. This, however works for me: `echo 'unset HISTFILE' >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `.bash_logout` file to specify commands that should be executed when logging out (see e.g. [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-run-commands-when-you-log-out/) for more information).

Answer (score 7):

The `bash` documentation (see `man bash`) includes this about history,

> **Shell Variables** The following variables are set by the shell:
>
> [...]
>
> **`HISTFILE`** The  name of the file in which command history is saved [...]. The default value is `~/.bash_history`. If unset, the command history is not saved when a shell exits.

So, to allow command history during a session but to prevent it being saved, simply unset this variable. You can do this in any or all of `.bash_profile`, `.profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

Answer (score 2):

`export HISTFILE=/dev/null`

It leaves old history untouched. It comes handy when you accidentally type a password or other data you do not want to share in .bash_history :-)